# Show that $\|Ax\|_2^2 = \lambda \|x\|_2^2$

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, normed-spaces, matrix-norms

> Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of $A^TA$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{0\}$ be the corresponding eigenvector, then show that $$\|Ax\|_2^2 = \lambda \|x\|_2^2 \ \text{and hence} \ \lambda  \geq 0$$

**Answer:**

Here $||.||_2$ denote matrix $ \ 2-$norm i.e, $||A||_2=\sigma_{\max} (A)=\sqrt{\lambda},$ where $\sigma_{\max}$ is the largest singular value of matrix $A$ and $\lambda$ is largest eigenvalue of $A^TA$.

Now we have,

$(A^TA)x=\lambda x \Rightarrow ||(A^TA)x||_2=||\lambda x||_2$

How to conclude the proof?

help me.

Since

Comment: Your 'answer' is not addressing the question asked. Use $\|Ax\|^2 = \langle Ax, Ax \rangle$.

Comment: You've got that wrong. It's $\left<Ax,Ax\right> = \left<x, (A^TA)x\right>$.

Comment: @copper.hat, sorry, unfortunate.  $||Ax||_2^2=<Ax,Ax>=\left\langle x,(A^TA)x \right\rangle=\left\langle x, \lambda x \right\rangle=\lambda <x,x>=\lambda ||x||_2^2$

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR: You got it!

Comment: @copper.hat, How to show that $||A||_2 \leq  ||A^TA||^{1/2}$ ? , where $||.||$ is a norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR: It is not true for an arbitrary norm.

Comment: @copper.hat, To prove $||A||_2 \leq  ||A^TA||^{1/2}$ , We know that $||A||_2=\sqrt \lambda$, Now if we show that $\lambda \leq ||A^TA||$ the we are done.  Can you help me ?

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR: You are asking a different question.

Comment: @copper.hat, here $||.||$ is a norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$ with associated subordinate matrix norm $||.||$ on $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$

Comment: @copper.hat, It is a subpart of the question. Can you hep me showing $ \lambda \leq ||A^TA||$, where $||.||$ and $\lambda$ as mentioned previous comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simpler proof is that $$||Ax||_2^2{=x^TA^TAx\\=x^T(A^TAx)\\=x^T(\lambda x)\\=x^T\lambda x\\=\lambda||x||_2^2}$$